# SQL JOIN with and

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

Some devs use `JOIN` and `AND` in this sql

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B
ON A.id = B.id AND B.date_begin < '2019' AND B.date_end > '2018'
WHERE B.group IN (..)
```

Which yield a different result if moving the condition in where part

```
SELECT * FROM A LEFT JOIN B
ON A.id = B.id 
WHERE B.group IN (..)
AND B.date_begin < '2019' AND B.date_end > '2018'
```

Why and how does the SQL is interpreted?

Comment: Could you post some sample data and expected behavior?

Comment: When you say different result, does it mean it return different amount of rows or same amount of rows but different field values?

Comment: Your 2 SQLs use `Left join`, so the data would be based on A's data, and the `where` clause's function is to filter the data based  on A, your filter condition is different ,so the result would get difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both things but with the clause in the join you will have a more structured query. It doesn't matter if you have a small query but with around 50 or more you loose the focus. I can recommend to use the AND instead of plenty of where conditions.

Comment: 'struktorized' - what's this in english?